# Twitter4j, trying to authenticate a second account from within the application shows an error message

Tags: java, twitter-oauth, twitter4j

So I am trying to authenticate users via the Twitter4j API. I am using the authentication method where a web page opens, the user clicks authorize, and then they get a code which they enter into the application. This works fine the first time, but when the authorization button is pressed again, even if a new twitter account is logged in on the main web browser, I see the message "You don't have access to PRODUCT_NAME"

The code I am using to set up the api is

```
twitter = TwitterFactory.getSingleton();
twitter.setOAuthConsumer(PROPERDATA, PROPERDATA);
try {
     requestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken();
} catch (TwitterException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Then to open the authentication page I do:

```
Desktop.getDesktop().browse( new URI(requestToken.getAuthorizationURL())
```

Is there a way to reset the twitter object to default so I can reinstantiate it, or am I thinking about this problem incorrectly?